# How should I resolve Cannot convert value of type 'Void' to expected argument type '() -> Void' by SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to pass `helloVM.hello()` to test2 view's action.
But then I got this error `Cannot convert value of type 'Void' to expected argument type '() -> Void'` at `test2(action: helloVM.hello())` in test1.

How should I fix `HelloViewModel's hello()`?

```
struct test1: View {
    @ObservedObject var helloVM = HelloViewModel()

    var body: some View{
       test2(action: helloVM.hello())
    }
}
```

```
struct test2: View {
    let action: ()-> Void

    var body: some View{
       Button(action: {
                  action()
              }, label: {
                  Text("hello")
               })
    }
}
```

```
class HelloViewModel: ObservableObject{
     func hello() -> Void{
         print("hello")
     }
}
```

I think `hello()` don't have any argument and return Void.
But compiler says such error.

Thank you

Comment: `test2(action: helloVM.hello)` remove the parenthesis

Comment: It did work! Thank you for a quick answer? But why only removing the parenthesis did success?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`test2(action: helloVM.hello)` remove the parenthesis

This is because.

`() -> Void` means "function that returns Void"

```
helloVM.hello()
```

Runs the function and returns a value.

You want to return the function, not the return of the function.

Comment: Make sense! Thank you. `() -> Void` just implies a function.

Comment: @Taro `() -> Void` is the notation for a type which is "function with no parameters and `Void` (i.e no) return type". If you have parameters in your function and a return type, it would look more like `(Int, String) -> Double` which is "function that takes an `Int` and a `String` as parameters and returns a `Double`".